# I don't have /etc/network/interfaces file

Tags: networking

I was trying to assign a static IP to eth0 (lan).

I was planning to modify the file `/etc/network/interfaces`. Instead of finding a full-fledged file there I found 4-5 lines modified or written by me (previously). I need the correct `/etc/network/interfaces` file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default `/etc/network/interfaces` on Ubuntu Desktop:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Anything else must be written by yourself (or, in general, by the system administrator).