# Destroyed NetworkManager?

Tags: networking, network-manager, ethernet

I've encountered a problem with NetworkManager in that it said that my ethernet connection was not managed. I searched for some fixes, but I guess in the end I screwed it up (edited interface etc.). In the end I've even removed/installed it again (a few times), but not to much success. Now not even the wireless seems to be working anymore (after a reboot). Fortunately, I still have WICD (found it as an alternative to NetworkManager). But I'd like to get NetworkManager back working.. is it possible to reinstall it so that it creates the ethernet and wireless connections again? Because I actually DELETED all ethernet connections in the "Edit Connections menu.." and I don't really know how to set it up again :).

Comment: "unmanaged" usually doesn't mean anything more sinister than that you have *chosen* to take control of the interface via the /etc/network/interfaces file. If you revert *that* then you shouldn't need to do anything special to get a default wired connection working again.

Comment: @steeldriver thank you for your answer, but how to do that? Where to get the original file from?

Comment: You can see the default contents in the answer here [I don't have /etc/network/interfaces file](http://askubuntu.com/a/857930/178692) - really, it's best to make a backup or at least comment your changes when editing unfamiliar system files

Comment: @steeldriver thank you. Sadly, it still does not seem to work. I think I have also edited/removed some other file..

Answer (score 0):

You can check which devices NetworkManager manages with

```
nmcli d
```

If your ethernet connection shows up as unmanaged, you should check if /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf has your ethernet connection managed = false. This should be true otherwise NetworkManager will ignore this device.

Otherwise you can check [network manager says "device not managed"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71159/network-manager-says-device-not-managed).